# Can i run WebAppContext with WebSocketHandler in same instance?

Tags: java, configuration, websocket, jetty, jetty-9

is it possible to run WebSocketHandler and WebAppContext together? I'm using latest version `9.2.1.v20140609`. I tried configuration below, but on Websocket call to `localhost:8080/` WebAppContext intercepts call. Here is my Launcher:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
    connector.setPort(8080);
    server.addConnector(connector);

    WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext("webapp", "/");

    // Setting up browser caching. Binds params for org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.init()
    context.getInitParams().put("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.etags", "true");
    context.getInitParams().put("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.cacheControl", "public, max-age=0");

    // Fix for Windows, so Jetty doesn't lock files
    if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("windows")) {
        context.getInitParams().put("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.useFileMappedBuffer", "false");
    }

    // Will throw an exception when will be unable to start server for some reason
    context.setThrowUnavailableOnStartupException(true);

    Broker broker = new Broker();

    // Implementation of org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketHandler
    WebSocketHandler socketHandler = new com.namespace.websocket.Handler(broker);

    HandlerCollection handlerCollection = new HandlerCollection();
    handlerCollection.setHandlers(new Handler[] {context, socketHandler});

    server.setHandler(handlerCollection);

    // Remove Server:Jetty(9...) from Response Headers
    removeServerVersionFromHeaders(server);

    server.start();

}
```

I can run from launcher multiple jetty instances and just wire WebSocket handler to some `5555` port, but preferably i would like to keep one Jetty instance, and maybe use `/ws` handler to manage WebSocket connections

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like:

```
public class Websock {
  private static class Adapter extends WebSocketAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onWebSocketConnect(Session sess) {
      System.out.print("client connected");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(8080);

    WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext("webapp", "/");
    context.getServletHandler().setEnsureDefaultServlet(false); // may or may not be needed.

    ContextHandlerCollection handlerCollection = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    handlerCollection.addHandler(context);
    handlerCollection.addHandler(createWebsocketHandler());

    server.setHandler(handlerCollection);

    server.start();
  }

  private static ContextHandler createWebsocketHandler() {
    ContextHandler contextHandler = new ContextHandler("/ws");
    contextHandler.setAllowNullPathInfo(true); // disable redirect from /ws to /ws/

    final WebSocketCreator webSocketcreator = new WebSocketCreator() {
      public Object createWebSocket(ServletUpgradeRequest request,
          ServletUpgradeResponse response) {
        return new Adapter();
      }
    };

    Handler webSocketHandler = new WebSocketHandler() {
      public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
        factory.setCreator(webSocketcreator);
      }
    };

    contextHandler.setHandler(webSocketHandler);
    return contextHandler;
  }
}
```

ContextHandlerCollection seems like what you want, takes a bit of getting used to chaining the jetty handlers together.

If you don't need the features of WebAppContext then you can remove that too and just use ContextHandlers directly.

I haven't ran this myself but it looks about right.

Answer (score 0):

**@Andrew,** i accept your answer. Code works but when you connect to `/ws` it throws `302` which redirects you to `/ws/`, so connect to `/ws/`.

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/ws");
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/ws' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302

var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/ws/");
```

I've been warned about this in `jetty-users` community, i asked kind of similar [question](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg04905.html) there, since nobody was answering. They are suggesting me to do it the other way, but I will try both approaches and will leave reply here shortly.

**EDIT:** Decided to stick with `WebSocketServlet`, and map it to existent WebAppContext

Comment: Ah yeah, forgot about that, you can use ContextHandler.setAllowNullPaths(true) to allow /ws. http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ContextHandler.html#setAllowNullPathInfo(boolean)